# Performance Issue in Infragistics Ignite UI Grid

Tags: javascript, infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

I am trying to integrate the Ignite UI igGrid control in my app when i try to load the grid with 1000 rows it works fine but when I try to load the grid with 10,000 or more rows the Chrome page stops responding.
Any one have tried with huge data set on Ignite UI please share the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Enable [Continuous Virtualization](http://www.igniteui.com/help/iggrid-virtualization-overview) on the igGrid. Virtualization will render only predefined rows in the DOM, improving the igGrid load time. Also check the [Performance Guide](http://www.igniteui.com/help/iggrid-performance-guide) topic to see what options affect performance.

The data volume is also a bottleneck. You should check in [Chrome developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) what's the time for the 10,000 rows to be fetched in the browser. If it's a couple of seconds consider enabling Gzip compression on the server.

Comment: i have found the solution thanks for your comment and you are right both fixed and continuous virtualization helps in the rendering the huge data.